# Is double is also kind of float?

Tags: java, types, floating-point, numbers, double

I heard that `double` is a more precise datatype and I would like to see the result of `double`
with the help of following program but still it is giving variable result each time similar but not exact to `float`.
What is the difference between `float` and `double` and when to use them in real time?
Can any body explain this scenario in simple terms
and specify the reason for this type of behaviour?

Thanks in advance :)

```
  public class DoubleResult {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double number=1;
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                number=number+0.1;
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }

    }
```

output:

```
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.5000000000000004
```

Comment: Also: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `float` and `double` are floating points. `float` is a single-precision (32 bit) floating point whereas `double` is a double-precision (hence the name) (64 bit)

```
Name    Width in Bits   Range
double  64              1.7e–308 to 1.7e+308
float   32              3.4e–038 to 3.4e+038
```

you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) for a more precise description of the precision issue with floating points

Answer (score 0):

A computer's floating point unit works with base 2 binary and 0.2 can't be represented precisely in binary, it is called a repeater fraction. In base-2 only numbers with denominators that are powers of 2 are terminating, which I think is only .25, .50, and .75, which is why 6.5 shows up as "same".

Imagine you had two decimal types, one with six significant digits, and one with sixteen.

What value would you use to represent pi for each of those types? In both cases you'd be trying to get as close to a number which you couldn't represent exactly - but you wouldn't end up with the same value, would you?

It's the same for float(32 bits) and double(64 bits) - both are binary floating point types, but double has more precision than float. so if you need precision then go for double.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more details